# any with two lists producing False when one substring is in string from other list

Tags: python

I want to see if any of the strings in `test` are in any of the items in `list`. I'm using `any` and anticipate getting `True` but get back `False`. What am I missing here?

```
test = ['AA', 'BB']
test_list = ['ABAB', 'AABB']

any(x in test_list for x in test)
>>> False

# should return True as 'BB' is in 'AABB or 'AA' in 'AABB'
```

Thanks!

Comment: it's behaving exactly like it should. 'AA' is *not* in `['ABAB', 'AABB']`

Comment: So the right question you should be asking is: how do i write the logic for what i want to match.

Comment: This is equivalent to `'AA' in test_list or 'BB' in test_list`; that's not true because `x in y` uses *equality*, not containment, to compare `x` to each element of `y`. For example, `'AA' in test_list` is equivalent to `'AA' == 'ABAB' or 'AA' == 'AABB'`, not `'AA' in 'ABAB' or 'AA in AABB'`.

Comment: @chepner That's interesting. So if `in` wasn't used on a list (e.g. `'AA' in 'AABB'`), would it be using containment in that case? I would think so because `'AA' in 'AABB'` is `True`

Comment: `'AA' in 'AABB'` is implemented with `str.__contains__`, while `'AA' in test_list` is implemented with `list.__contains__`.

Answer (score 1):

You are not testing whether an element of the first list, e.g. `"AA"`, is in an element of the second list, e.g., `"AABB"`, but whether `"AA"` is in `['ABAB', 'AABB']`, which it is not. Instead, I think you want:

```
a = ['AA', 'BB']
b = ['ABAB', 'AABB']

any(x in el for x in a for el in b)
```

This will test whether any element of `a` is a substring of any element of `b`.

I renamed the lists since you should avoid using built-in names like `list` for your variables.